# Autofilter not returning anticipated values

Tags: excel, vba, date, autofilter

I have a macro in Excel that opens (a different) Excel workbook and applies 2 filter criteria to a data column. However it is not returning any rows. When I filter that workbook manually it does return rows.

```
    msoWb.Activate
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A:Z")
        .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=">=" & dtFrom, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & dtTo
    End With
```

dtFrom and dtTo are of type Double, that hold the integer representations of the dates.

Interestingly, the below works (where I have just one date equality criterion) but as soon as I apply 2 it returns nothing (when doing it in code but returns data when doing it manually as previously mentioned).

`AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=dtFrom)`

I have no idea why this isnt working when using >= and <=

Sub ImportData()

```
Dim msoWb As Workbook
Dim fullFileName As String
Dim newTabName As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim strDtFrom As Variant
Dim dtFrom As Double
Dim strDtTo As Variant
Dim dtTo As Double
Dim feesWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim newWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim feesRange As Range
Dim valRange As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim propertyValue As Variant
Dim valuationType As Variant
Dim matchRow As Variant
Dim custResultValue As Variant
Dim atomResultValue As Variant
Dim row As Range
Dim feeColumnCustomer As Integer
Dim feeColumnAtom As Integer

strDtFrom = InputBox("Enter FROM date:", "Date", Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy"))

If IsDate(strDtFrom) Then
    dtFrom = CDbl(CDate(strDtFrom))
Else
    MsgBox "Invalid FROM date! Re-run the Macro."
    Exit Sub
End If

strDtTo = InputBox("Enter TO date:", "Date", Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy"))

If IsDate(strDtTo) Then
    dtTo = CDbl(CDate(strDtTo))
    If dtTo < dtFrom Then
        MsgBox "TO date cannot be less than FROM date! Re-run the Macro."
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "Invalid TO date! Re-run the Macro."
    Exit Sub
End If

fullFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv")

If fullFileName = "" Or fullFileName = "False" Then
    MsgBox ("No file selected. Re-run the Macro.")
    Exit Sub
End If

Set thisWb = ThisWorkbook

newTabName = Format(Now, "dd.mm.yy hh.MM.ss")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
wb.Activate
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Name = newTabName

Set msoWb = Workbooks.Open(fullFileName)
msoWb.Activate


With ActiveSheet.Range("A:Z")
    .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=">=" & dtFrom, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & dtTo
End With

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
wb.Activate
rng.Copy wb.Worksheets(newTabName).Range("A1")

msoWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
wb.Activate

Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert
Cells(1, 2).Value = "Customer Amount £"
Range("C1").EntireColumn.Insert
Cells(1, 3).Value = "Atom Amount £"
Cells(1, 19).Value = "Valuation Type"
Columns("B:Z").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
ActiveSheet.Range("E:F,H:I,K:K,M:O,Q:Q").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

Set feesWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fee Rates")
Set newWorksheet = ActiveSheet
Set feesRange = feesWorksheet.Range("A1:N1000")

Set valRange = newWorksheet.Range("A2:T" & newWorksheet.Cells(newWorksheet.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).row)

For Each row In valRange.Rows
    For Each cell In row.Cells
        If cell.column = 7 Then
            propertyValue = cell.Value
        ElseIf cell.column = 19 Then
            valuationType = cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
    
    feeColumnCustomer = 0
    feeColumnAtom = 0
    
    Select Case valuationType
        Case "Basic valuation"
            feeColumnCustomer = 4
            feeColumnAtom = 3
        Case "Homebuyer Survey"
            feeColumnCustomer = 6
            feeColumnAtom = 5
        Case "Building Survey"
            feeColumnCustomer = 8
            feeColumnAtom = 7
        Case "Re-type"
            feeColumnCustomer = 10
            feeColumnAtom = 9
        Case "Re-inspection"
            feeColumnCustomer = 12
            feeColumnAtom = 11
    End Select
    
    matchRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(propertyValue, feesRange.Columns(1), 1)
    
    If feeColumnCustomer = 0 Then
        custResultValue = "Unknown"
    Else
        custResultValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(feesRange.Columns(feeColumnCustomer), matchRow)
    End If
    
    Cells(row.row, 2).Value = custResultValue
    
    If feeColumnAtom = 0 Then
        atomResultValue = "Unknown"
    Else
        atomResultValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(feesRange.Columns(feeColumnAtom), matchRow)
    End If
    
    Cells(row.row, 3).Value = atomResultValue
    
    newWorksheet.Range("B2:C" & newWorksheet.Cells(newWorksheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
Next row

valRange.Sort Key1:=Range("L1"), Order1:=xlAscending

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Add `CDbl`: `Criteria1:=">=" & Cdbl(dtFrom), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(dtTo)`

Comment: thanks. i will try that, although they are already of type Double?

Comment: Sorry - I missed that (your variable naming is confusing then!)

Comment: yes poor use good shout :-)

Comment: UPDATE - i have noticed that it is only returning dates <= 12th day of the month - suggesting there is something going on with date formats... but I am usind the Double data type which is an integer representation of the date so not sure why it is having an issue?

Comment: You should add data example and expected output

Comment: I think you need to post more of the code - especially the declaration line(s) for those variables.

Comment: i have updated - thank you!